# Problem with enabling a button in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 jQuery functions:

```
$('#bt_capture').click(function() {
        webcam.snap();
        $('#bt_capture').attr('disabled', true); 
        $('#bt_capture').hide();
        $('#bt_re_capture').show();
});
```

and

```
$('#bt_re_capture').click(function() {  
        webcam.reset();
        $('#bt_re_capture').hide();
        $('#bt_capture').show();
        $('#bt_capture').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

The problem is that `$('#bt_capture').removeAttr('disabled');` doesn't enable a button. I also tried other ways, like **$(..).prop(...)** or **(document).getElementById**.. and more, but they all don't work.

Comment: are you sure you are not disabling your button anywhere else?

Comment: Prop should work.. http://jsfiddle.net/BfD7p/ Are you sure it reaches the handler.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: `$('#bt_capture').attr('disabled', false);`?

Comment: try `$('#bt_capture').attr('disabled', false);`

Comment: So many questions: Are you sure that is the id and it is not a class, doesn't it invoke the handler? DO you have duplicate id? etc.. So to get a solution demonstrate your problem in a fiddle to replicate.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
$('#bt_capture').prop('disabled', false);
```

On the other side, I'm not sure why you're disabling an invisible element.

Comment: OP said he tried `prop` and was unable to get it to work. "I also tried other ways, like $(..).prop(...) or (document).getElementById.. and more, but they all don't work."

Comment: `prop` is for jQuery since 1.6, afaik. Not crucial but still.

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum: this is the code he needs to enable a element with `id = bt_capture`. I don't see this exact code on his question. Maybe he used it wrong.

Comment: I already tried this code, doen't work.

Comment: @DarkSun We can't help you without further information. Would you mind creating a fiddle (on jsfiddle.net or codepen.io) illustrating your issue with a reduced case?

Comment: Work on jsFiddle. Also the strange thing is prop('disabled', false); works from debug console.Could it be because multiple jQuery versions are included?

Comment: @DarkSun: that could be a problem. No question you should get rid of one of them

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working!:)

```
$('#bt_capture').show(function() {
            $('#bt_capture').prop('disabled', false);
            webcam.reset();
});
```